# Trying to parse string into struct members

Tags: c, parsing, csv

I have the following members in a `struct`:

```
typedef struct rect RECTANGLE;
struct rect
{
  char command[16];
  int width;
  int height;
  int x;
  int y;
};
```

i want to parse the following input string into above struct:

```
new 3,4+7,8
```

For now i have the following code:

```
printf("Command input? ");
  scanf("%15[^,]%d,%d+%d,%d",
        new_rect.command,
        atoi(&new_rect.height),
        atoi(&new_rect.width),
        atoi(&new_rect.x),
        atoi(&new_rect.y));

  printf("Command: %i\n", new_rect.command);
  printf("Height: %i\n", new_rect.height);
  printf("Width: %i\n", new_rect.width);
  printf("x: %i\n", new_rect.x);
  printf("y: %i\n", new_rect.y);
```

Comment: `printf("Command: %i\n",...` should be `%s`

Comment: Why do you have `atoi` calls inside `scanf` ? It doesn't make any sense, remove them.

Comment: Note that `%15[^,]` will read "new 3" which isn't what you want. Also you need to *read* the comma which terminates `%15[^,]` or the subsequent `%d` will fail. And ***always*** check the return value from `scanf()` which should have been `5` .

Comment: I get this warning...

: warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
        atoi(&new_rect.height),
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: You usage of `atoi` doesn't make any sense. Explain us why you think `atoi` is useful here. While explaining you might find out by yourself why using `atoi` here is nonsense.

Comment: `atoi` is supposed to take a string and return `int`.

Comment: `if(scanf("%15s%d ,%d +%d ,%d", new_rect.command, &new_rect.height, &new_rect.width, &new_rect.x, &new_rect.y) == 5)` assuming that the command is a single word.

Comment: @WeatherVane, your answer is right!
Can you please upgrade it to answer?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code's `%15[^,]` will read up to the first comma, i.e. `"new 3"` which isn't what you want. Also you need to read the comma which terminates `%15[^,]` or the subsequent `%d` will fail. And *always* check the return value from `scanf()` which should have been `5`.

Assuming that the command is a single word, this code seems to do the job. There was also an error in `%s` being `%i` for a string in the first `printf`

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct rect
{
    char command[16];
    int width;
    int height;
    int x;
    int y;
} new_rect;

int main(void){

    if(scanf("%15s%d ,%d +%d ,%d", new_rect.command, &new_rect.height, &new_rect.width, &new_rect.x, &new_rect.y) == 5) {

        printf("Command: %s\n", new_rect.command);
        printf("Height: %i\n", new_rect.height);
        printf("Width: %i\n", new_rect.width);
        printf("x: %i\n", new_rect.x);
        printf("y: %i\n", new_rect.y);
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

If have added some extra spaces in the format string to make it more tolerant of spaces that might be input. That's not necessary before `%d`, which filters whitespace anyway.

Running the program with the input shown gives

```
new 3,4+7,8
Command: new
Height: 3
Width: 4
x: 7
y: 8
```